# Set Status "Out of Office" in Event

Tags: trigger, event

I have written Trigger which creates Event Under Account.
Now I have to set Event status as "out Of office"

```
event.ShowAs = 'Out of Office';
```

The value is already present there
[image]
For "Busy" Status It works fine
But For "Out Of Office"
It returns Exception.

> first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Show Time As:
>   bad value for restricted picklist field: Out of Office: [ShowAs]

Answer (score 1):

I was going to just comment on Nuno's answer but alas, I don't have the reputation. Not sure why it was downvoted. For some reason, Salesforce stores the value as Nuno wrote:

```
event.ShowAs = 'OutofOffice'
```

I came across this when writing an event trigger that checked if the event Show Time As field equals 'Out of Office'. It only works if I compare the value to 'OutofOffice'.

```
if(e.ShowAs == 'OutofOffice')
```

'Out of Office' is incorrect in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

A picklist contains all the values you are allowed to set for the field in a record. You didn't insert the value 'Out of Office' in your picklist 'ShowAs': https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_creating_picklists.htm&language=en_US

Comment: The picklist value is standard. It is already present

Answer (score -1):

You have to write it like this:

```
event.ShowAs = 'OutofOffice';
```

it worked for me :)